# How to put text into circle in WPF XAML template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates

How to put text into circle in WPF XAML template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, like on [Centering Text on a WPF Shape](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/12/15/centering-text-on-a-wpf-shape.aspx)

Here's an example:

```
<Border CornerRadius="50"
        Width="60"
        Height="60"
        Margin="10"
        Padding="0,20,0,0"
        Background="Aquamarine"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1">
  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Test
  </TextBlock>
</Border>
```